# How to use set_value but does'nt using form_validation set_rules?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, setvalue

I have an algorithm like this :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('costs/v_addcontainer', $data);
    } elseif ($check_valid_qty == "error" || $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('qty_error', 'Quantity not valid!');
         redirect('Cost/add_container');
    } elseif ($check_data_selling > 0) {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('data_exist', 'Data already exists!');
         redirect('Cost/add_container');
    } else{
        // insert data
    }
```

If the data already exists, the system will alert "Data already exists" but I want the previous value set on form. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be loading your view again in the "fail" cases instead of redirecting.

The "Data already exists" message is showing because you're setting it as flashdata, which will persist across a redirect, but everything else is essentially lost, so if you want to repopulate the form using `set_value()`, you need to show it within the current request.

This also means you don't need to mess with the session data, and can just pass your alert messages in normally.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $this->load->view('costs/v_addcontainer', $data);
} elseif ($check_valid_qty == "error") {
     $data['qty_error'] = 'Quantity not valid!';
     $this->load->view('costs/v_addcontainer', $data);
} elseif ($check_data_selling > 0) {
     $data['data_exist'] = 'Data already exists!';
     $this->load->view('costs/v_addcontainer', $data);
} else{
    // insert data
}
```

Ideally, though, you should be looking up the documentation for form validation callbacks, as they'll allow you to feed your extra rules into the form validation class with no need for the extra logic here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer